# Out of memory : Permgen space issue while drools 6.1.0 Kibase configuration with spring

Tags: spring, drools, kie

We are migrating rules from drools 5.3.0 to drools 6.1.0  Getting permgen space error while loading drools 6 Kibase configution,

We are  using spring and dool 6 integration instead KModule.xml  for loading and execution of the rules

Here is brief what we are doing  :

1) Defined spring based Kiebase configuration  which has almost  200 Kibase

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd

```
  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd

  http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd">

<kie:kmodule id="TEST_KIE_MODULE">

    <kie:kbase name="KIE_BASE_1"  packages="rules.test1"/>
     <kie:kbase name="KIE_BASE_2"  packages="rules.test2"/> 
      .
      .
      .
      .
     <kie:kbase name="KIE_BASE_200"  packages="rules.test2"/>  


<bean id="kiePostProcessor" class="org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor">
    <constructor-arg name="configFileURL" value=""></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="configFilePath" value="../TestApp/src/main/resources"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

2)When we have less no of KB for examples 20 it was working fine with 512 permgen space . AS we added few more KibeBase configuration started permgen space issue while loadind rules.

3) Here is brief what we are doing :

1)WE have first compiling entire KB configuration (application start up ) and storing in tocache . 
 2) While executing rules we are getting qualified KB based on certain input parameters and firing all rules from that KB .
 3)Each KB we have average 50-60 rules . 
 4) In step 1 we are getting issue of perm gen space with 512 .

Your help will be appriciated on this . Same conifiguration was working with drool 5.3.0 but getting issue in drools 6.1.0

Comment: Have you tried changing standalone.config file. Please increase -Xms and -Xmx form 1303m(default). you can find standalone.conf inside the bin.